# Sorting Generic Lists with CompareTo

Tags: c#, list, sorting, generics, compareto

I am trying to figure out the correct way to sort a generic list of objects.  A quick example of my data structure:

```
// The base class
public abstract class Item : IComparable<Item> {
    public enum Category { Hats, Shirts, ... }
    public Category category;

    public int CompareTo (Item that) {
       ...
    }
}

// One of several classes extending Item
public class Hat : Item {
    public int CompareTo (Hat that) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I have a manager class that maintains lists for each class that extends Item:

```
Dictionary<Item.Category, List<Item>> _items;

...

foreach (Item.Category category in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Item.Category))) {
    List<Item> list = _items[category];
    list.Sort();
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I call `List<Item>.Sort()`, it's obviously not making use of the class-specific `CompareTo()` functions.  What's the proper way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `List<Item>.Sort()` is looking for an implementation of `IComparable<Item>` which your derived class does not implement.  You've added a `CompareTo(Hat hat)` method which has *nothing* to do with your `IComparable<Item>` implementation other than they happen to have the same name. You *could* make `CompareTo` virtual and overload it, but then you'd have to change the signature of the override:

```
// The base class
public abstract class Item : IComparable<Item> {
    public enum Category { Hats, Shirts, ... }
    public Category category;

    public virtual int CompareTo (Item that) {
       // default implementation
    }
}

// One of several classes extending Item
public class Hat : Item {
    public override int CompareTo (Item that) {
       // override for Hats - can Hats be compared to other Items?
    }
}
```

also be *very* careful that your CompareTo is *symmetric* and *transitive* or your sort will fail:

Symmetric : if a < b then b > a

Transitive: If a < b and b < c then a < c

I've seen implementations of `CompareTo` that aren't transitive and it is tough to diagnose and fix.

You should also take the time to [override Equals and the comparison operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182163%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly the solution I was looking for, but couldn't figure out :).  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you can't just use the built in compare that c# comes with ?

`list.OrderByDescending(..)` or `list.OrderBy(..)`

if you want to choose to use `Icomparable` then you have to tell it what to compare 
ex.

```
list.Sort((x,y) => x.Category.CompareTo(y.Category));
```

Comment: Each class has its own sorting logic implemented in CompareTo, so I don't think I can make that work with OrderByDescending/OrderBy.

Comment: no you cant , I was just curious , since you didn't post the sorting logic , if it was just generic sort.  but it should work when you pass what parameter to sort with lambda like my example